# Arch Linux doesn't recognize sound driver - "dummy output"

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio

I have a Dell G7 that I installed Arch Linux on and I have no audio on my speakers, only my bluetooth headphones. On `pavucontrol`, the output device is labeled "Dummy Output", which leads me to believe the OS isn't recognizing my sound card. I tried running `pacmd list-cards` which gave the following output:

```
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0x83000000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "10f9"
        device.product.name = "TU106 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "TU106 High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra5: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra5: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra5: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra6: Digital Stereo (HDMI 7) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra6: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 7) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra6: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 7) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                ...
```

So I tried to make my system recognize `alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1` with the command:

```
pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

But it didn't work. I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that I only have `output:hdmi-*` profiles, whereas other solutions have `output:analog-stereo`. Does anybody have any ideas?

For more information, here is the output of this [alsa-info](https://gist.github.com/craftyjon/902247) script:

```
!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Arch Linux release ID_LIKE=arch


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Dell Inc.
Product Name:      G7 7500
Product Version:
Firmware Version:  1.3.0
System SKU:        09F3
Board Vendor:      Dell Inc.
Board Name:        0VF32T


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/CUST0001:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DLLK09F3:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D5:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3400:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3450:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:03/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:04/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:05/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:06/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXVIDEO:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:00/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:01/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:05/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C04:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP00001:00/status     11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/USBC000:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/WCOM508E:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:16/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:7d/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.9.13-arch1-1
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         unknown
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.9.13-arch1-1
Library version:    1.2.4
Utilities version:  1.2.4


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes

Jack:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/jackd)
      Running - No


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x83000000 irq 17


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS [8086:06c8]
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:09f3]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f9] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:09f3]


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Nvidia GPU 93 HDMI/DP
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x10de0093
Subsystem Id: 0x102809f3
Revision Id: 0x100100
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x04 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Devices: 4
     Dev 00: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
     Dev 01: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
     Dev 02: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
    *Dev 03: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=05, enabled=1
  Devices: 4
     Dev 00: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
     Dev 01: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
     Dev 02: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
    *Dev 03: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=09, enabled=1
  Devices: 4
     Dev 00: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
     Dev 01: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
     Dev 02: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
    *Dev 03: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=0d, enabled=1
  Devices: 4
     Dev 00: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
     Dev 01: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
     Dev 02: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
    *Dev 03: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x08 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x09 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x0a [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x0b [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/pcmC0D10p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/pcmC0D11p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/pcmC0D12p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Dec 14 18:01 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Dec 14 18:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 280 Dec 14 18:01 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Dec 14 18:01 pci-0000:01:00.1 -> ../controlC0


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card NVidia

Card hw:0 'NVidia'/'HDA NVidia at 0x83000000 irq 17'
  Mixer name    : 'Nvidia GPU 93 HDMI/DP'
  Components    : 'HDA:10de0093,102809f3,00100100'
  Controls      : 49
  Simple ctrls  : 7
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',4
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',5
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',6
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: I managed to fix my problem using [this solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Inspiron_15_(7590)#Use_legacy_HDA-Intel_driver).

Create the following file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/audio-fix.conf
---------------------------------------------------------

blacklist snd-sof-pci
options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1
```

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this problem on my Dell G7 7500 by installing `alsa-firmware`, `sof-firmware`, and `alsa-ucm-conf`, as recommended by the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#ALSA_firmware).

Comment: For me, all that was necessary was `sof-firmware` which, as I understand it contains support for some of the more modern audio devices (I'm on a recent Thinkpad T14s).